# Why my OR operator doesn't work on XPATH?

Tags: xpath, operators

I've tried both

```
//th[text()="Seller Finanacing Available"]/following-sibling::td[text()="Yes" OR text()=""]
```

and

```
//th[text()="Seller Finanacing Available"]/following-sibling::td[text()="Yes"|text()=""]
```

but both don't work. What do I do wrong when I want to use OR operator in XPATH for attribute value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the OR should be lowercase instead

```
//th[text()="Seller Finanacing Available"]/following-sibling::td[text()="Yes" or text()=""]
```